# Titles not showing for tabs pages

Tags: 7, routes

Below is the array in my hook_menu

The only issue that I have with it is that the titles are not displaying for tabs pages (the last three array collections).

They are showing the title for the parent: 'Affiliate Hoover Home page'.

I've tried title callback instead but that isn't working

```
$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover'] = array(
    'title' => 'Affiliate Hoover Home page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'description' => 'This is the affiliate hoover homepage - add shit here',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array('affiliate_hoover_first_form'),
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.home.inc',
    'menu_name' => 'Affiliate Hoover',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/uniquename/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_unique_name',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(4),
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.uniquename.inc',
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB,
    'title callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_uniquename_title_callback',
    'title arguments' => array(4),
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/uniqueform/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_unique_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page arguments' => array(4),
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.uniqueform.inc',
    'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB,
    'title callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_unique_form_title_callback',
    'title arguments' => array(4),
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/ajax'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.ajax.inc',
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_ajax_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Home',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => -10);

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.delete.inc',
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_delete_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/log'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.log.inc',
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_log_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

$items['admin/config/affiliate_hoover/tracking'] = array(
    'title' => 'Tracking',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'affiliate_hoover.tracking.inc',
    'page callback' => 'affiliate_hoover_tracking_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

return $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have static titles of submenus I suggest you to return using 'title' value in array.

I guess: set static titles and 'title callback' to false.

Answer (score 0):

There is [drupal_set_title](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) you can try this in menu callback functions.

```
drupal_set_title($title = NULL, $output = CHECK_PLAIN);
```

> **Parameters**
>
> **$title:** Optional string value to assign to the page title; or if set to NULL (default), leaves the current title unchanged.
>
> **$output:** Optional flag - normally should be left as CHECK_PLAIN. Only set to PASS_THROUGH if you have already removed any possibly
>   dangerous code from $title using a function like check_plain() or
>   filter_xss(). With this flag the string will be passed through
>   unchanged.
>
> **Return value**
>
> The updated title of the current page.